# What does "$\to$" mean in "$a^3+b^3=(a+b)^3\rightarrow ab(a+b)=0$"?

Tags: functions, notation

I'm working on [this](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/2006_AIME_I_Problems/Problem_12) problem and I'm having difficulty understanding the solution. In the solution, it states $a^3+b^3=(a+b)^3\rightarrow ab(a+b)=0$. What do these equations mean? It doesn't seem to fit the identity $a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)$ if the arrow meant subtracting.

I know that right arrows can define a function, but I don't see how $(a+b)^3\rightarrow ab(a+b)=0$ could be a function. If it is, then I don't know how it is applicable to the problem, in which case it would be great if someone could explain the rest of the solution.

*P.
S.* I don't see this as asking two questions if that's not allowed. One is just a prerequisite to the other.

Comment: The argument is asserting that $a^3+ b^3 = ( a+b)^3$, then indicating that this relation *leads to* ("$\to$") $ab(a+b)=0$. That kind of notation probably makes more sense in displayed equations like  $$a^3+ b^3 = ( a+b)^3 \qquad\to\qquad ab(a+b)=0$$ (At least, I hope it makes sense ... I do this all the time!) Incorporating it into text probably isn't the best presentation.

Comment: $“A\to B”$ means that whenever $A$ is true, then $B$ is also true.

Comment: Some people use $\Rightarrow$ in the context where $\rightarrow$ is used here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that
$$
a^3  + b^3  = \left( {a + b} \right)^3 
$$
Since
$$
\left( {a + b} \right)^3  = a^3  + b^3  + 3a^2 b + 3ab^2 
$$
it follows that
$$
3a^2 b + 3ab^2  = 0
$$
thus
$$
3ab\left( {a + b} \right) = 0
$$
so that
$$
ab\left( {a + b} \right) = 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

It means: if $a^3+b^3 =(a+b)^3$, then  $ab (a+b)=0$.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, the arrow is a symbol which describes the logical flow of the argument being made.  It should be read as "implies" or "leads to".  That is, if $A$ and $B$ are two statements, then the notation
$$A \to B$$
can be read "$A$ implies $B$", or "$A$ leads to $B$".  Alternatively, this can also be read as "If $A$ is a true statement, then $B$ is a true statement as well", or, more succinctly, "If $A$, then $B$".

In the context of the particular argument presented in the question, the notation
$$ a^3+b^3=(a+b)^3\rightarrow ab(a+b)=0 $$
means that the truth of the first equation implies the truth of the second equation.  Written with sightly less notation, we might say

> If $a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)^3$, then $ab(a+b)=0$.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3428057/468350) shows how one might obtain that result.  Written more compactly, one might write

\begin{align}
&a^3 + b^3 = (a+b)^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3 && \text{(expand the RHS)} \\
&\qquad\rightarrow 0 = 3a^2b + 3ab^2 = 3ab(a^2+b^2) && \text{(cancel $a^3+b^3$, factor)} \\
&\qquad\rightarrow 0 = ab(a^2 + b^2). && \text{(cancel $3$)}
\end{align}

Answer (score -1):

the arrow means it follows:  just calculate (a+b)^3 and subtract a^3+b^3
 what remains is 0

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1277793)

Comment: @Klangen, I think it does answer the question. The arrow means from the first it follows the second. One must expand the LHS and substract the RHS from it.